# Serialize/Deserialize using JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

My goal is to convert a JSON string field to the right class using Jackson.

I have the following class:

```
public class AnimalRecord {

    private String id;
    private String source;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "source", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CatProbeMetadata.class, name 
 = "catProbeMetadata"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DogProbeMetadata.class, name = "dogProbeMetadata"),
            })
   private AnimalMetadata metadata;
```

In addition to this class, I have a DB table where I store records of AnimalRecord (AnimalRecord = row). The AnimalMetadata is a different JSON string based on the `source` of this class. Each source has it's own `metadata` and class definition. In this example, CatProbeMetadata class will be the output when doing de-serialization from the string when the source is "cat".

The issue is that I'm not sure what to do when reading the rows from the DB. I have the following method:

```
private class ActiveProbeWrapper implements RowMapper<ActiveProbeRecord> {

        @Override
        public ActiveProbeRecord mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            String id= rs.getString("id");
            String source= rs.getString("source");
            Animalmetadata metadata = // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE;
            ActiveProbeRecord record = new ActiveProbeRecord(deviceId,segment, source, metadata);
            return record;
        }

    }
```

I need to convert the string in the DB to the right class instance, but my metadata string will NOT include the source (since it's outside the metadata JSON).

**The question: Will I have to add the "source" field to the metadata itself or is there any better way of doing this that I missed?**

**Updated example:**
Example of DB rows:
id | source | metadata
1 | catSource | {"catName": "Mewy"}
2 | dogSource | {"dogName": "Barky"}

When I read the rows from the DB I want to use the `source` field to de-serialize `metadata` to the right class - String --> `CatMetadata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property` attribute of the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation marks the property that defines the entity subclass, and `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` means that this property should be included not inside the `metadata` value, but on an upper level, as a property of the `AnimalRecord` class. This will only work if you parse the string as the `AnimalRecord` class.

This property should contain the value `catProbeMetadata` for cats and `dogProbeMetadata` of dogs, otherwise Jackson won't know how to parse the contents of your `source` field. The property may be also included inside the `source` string itself, but then you have to use `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`.

### Approach 1 - type is inside the metadata

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CatProbeMetadata.class, name = "catProbeMetadata"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DogProbeMetadata.class, name = "dogProbeMetadata"),
})
class AnimalMetadata {

    private String type;
}

class CatProbeMetadata extends AnimalMetadata {

    private String catName;
}

class DogProbeMetadata extends AnimalMetadata {

    private String dogName;
}

class AnimalRecord {

    private AnimalMetadata metadata;
}
```

Then you could parse it as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

AnimalRecord catRecord = new AnimalRecord();
catRecord.setMetadata(mapper.readValue("{\"type\":\"catProbeMetadata\",\"catName\": \"Paws\"}", AnimalMetadata.class));

AnimalRecord dogRecord = new AnimalRecord();
dogRecord.setMetadata(mapper.readValue("{\"type\":\"dogProbeMetadata\",\"dogName\": \"Fido\"}", AnimalMetadata.class));
```

### Approach 2 - type is outside of metadata

Just select the class manually, based on the type. You don't need any annotations:

```java
class AnimalMetadata {
}

class CatProbeMetadata extends AnimalMetadata {
    private String catName;
}

class DogProbeMetadata extends AnimalMetadata {
    private String dogName;
}

class AnimalRecord {

    private String type;

    private AnimalMetadata metadata;
}
```

Then you can parse like this. Putting the selection logic inside a separate method has exactly same consequences as putting it into annotations - you just need to update a different piece of code if you want to add a new subclass:

```java
public Class<? extends AnimalMetadata> getMetadataClass(AnimalRecord record) {
    switch (record.getType()) {
        case "cat":
            return CatProbeMetadata.class;
        case "dog":
            return DogProbeMetadata.class;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public void parse() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    AnimalRecord catRecord = new AnimalRecord();
    catRecord.setType("cat");
    catRecord.setMetadata(mapper.readValue("{\"catName\": \"Paws\"}", getMetadataClass(catRecord)));

    AnimalRecord dogRecord = new AnimalRecord();
    dogRecord.setType("dog");
    dogRecord.setMetadata(mapper.readValue("{\"dogName\": \"Fido\"}", getMetadataClass(dogRecord)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergei, great answer! But I don't understand why you `setSource` to the `catRecord` with the type and catname, I thought the `source` should be just `cat` and metadata` should include all the metadata (like cat name) of the inner class. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow, probably by "inner class" you mean a subclass? As I understood, you have a string field in the database that may contain data of different types, so you want to parse it polymorphically (specifying only the root class `AnimalMetadata` and letting Jackson figure out the actual subclass to use). `catName` and `dogName` are just examples of fields that may be different in the `AnimalMetadata` subclasses. They might as well contain exactly the same set of fields, but then it's not clear why do you need different subclasses for them. Hope my answer makes sense.

Comment: @TheUnreal I think I see the "source" of confusion - I thought your "source" field contains the JSON you want to parse, and you want to keep the original string there also as part of your data model. I've updated the example.

Comment: Still not, What you said in the comment was right - but I expect the fields that may be different will be set inside the `metadata` of the parent class and not in the `type` field, which should be a simple string - `cat` or `dog`. I added an example in my question. EDIT: I see you comments, Thanks, let me check

Comment: So I understand that you don't want to add the `source` field inside metadata itself. As far as I know, parsing JSON depending on some external field is not possible. You could as well just do a `switch(record.source)` and select the class to parse based on that. This doesn't really differ from specifying the same information in the annotation.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Jackson 2.12 introduced a
[new feature for type deduction](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-most-wanted-1-5-deduction-based-polymorphism-c7fb51db7818) :

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(DogMetadata.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(CatMetadata.class) })
public abstract class AnimalMetadata {
}
```

and therefore:

```java
AnimalMetadata metadata = om.readValue("{\"catName\": \"Paws\"}", AnimalMetadata.class);
assertThat(metadata).isInstanceOf(CatMetadata.class);
```

The downside is that it might break if Jackson can't figure out which subtype to use based solely on properties names.
With this solution, optional json fields (like an absent `catName` property), or too similar subtypes may rise problems.  @Sergei solutions doesn't have these issues (also, his solution makes use of the `source` field, which was your requirement).

On a side note, if you're working with SpringBoot, upgrading jackson is a matter of adding this property in `pom.xml`

```xml
        <jackson-bom.version>2.12.3</jackson-bom.version>
```